# How to manipulate the ScrollController in Flutter's sliding up panel plugin?

Tags: flutter, dart, plugins

I'm using Flutter's [sliding_up_panel](https://pub.dev/packages/sliding_up_panel) plugin.

I want to scroll the panel to the top when a new item is selected from my app drawer. Presently selecting a new item closes the panel and refreshes the panel content. Then opens it to a 200px peak, but it doesn't reset the panel's Scroll location to the top.

I've been going around in circles trying the same solutions in slightly different ways and getting nowhere.

What I've tried:
I have global

```
  PanelController slidingPanelController = new PanelController();
  ScrollController slideUpPanelScrollController = new ScrollController();
```

I tried attaching my global `slideUpPanelScrollController` to my panel's listview, but when swiping up the panel's ListView it simultaneously starts closing the whole panel. If you were scrolling up to read the content you'd skimmed, well, you're not able to because it's disappearing.

Preventing this bug is easy, you do it the canonical way from the plugin's examples, pass the ScrollController through from `SlidingPanel` and therefore create a local ScrollController in the panel's Listview.

```
panelBuilder: (slideUpPanelScrollController) => _scrollingList(presentLocation, slideUpPanelScrollController)
```

The problem then is, you can't scroll the panel on new App drawer selections, because the controller is now local.

I tried putting a listener on the local listview ScrollController, `_slideUpPanelScrollController` and testing for panelController.close():

```
if(slidingPanelController.isPanelClosed) _slideUpPanelScrollController.jumpTo(0);
```

But the listener blocked the panel from swiping, swipe events fired but the panel didn't swipe, or was extremely reluctant too.

Having freshly selected content open in the panel displaying content halfway down the ListView is a glitchy user experience. I would love some ideas or better solutions.

I need it so when the panel is closed, I can
`slideUpPanelScrollController.jumpTo(0);`

I need the global controller to attach to the panel ListView's local controller, or I need a way to access the local controller to fire its Scroll from outwith my  `_scrollingList()` function.

Here's the panel Widget:

```
  SlidingUpPanel(
    key: Key("slidingUpPanelKey"),
    borderRadius: slidingPanelBorderRadius,
    parallaxEnabled: false,
    controller: slidingPanelController,
    isDraggable: isDraggableBool,
    onPanelOpened: () {
    },
    onPanelSlide: (value) {
      if (value >= 0.98)
        setState(() {
          slidingPanelBorderRadius =
              BorderRadius.vertical(top: Radius.circular(16));
        });
    },
    onPanelClosed: () async {
      setState(() {
        listViewScrollingOff = true;
      });
      imageZoomController.value =
          Matrix4.identity(); // so next Panel doesn't have zoomed in image

      slidingPanelBorderRadius =
          BorderRadius.vertical(top: Radius.circular(16));
    },
    minHeight: panelMinHeight,
    maxHeight:
        MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - AppBar().preferredSize.height,
    panelBuilder: (slideUpPanelScrollController) => _scrollingList(presentLocation, slideUpPanelScrollController),
    body: ...
```

Here's the _scrollingList Widget:

```
  Widget _scrollingList(LocationDetails presentLocation, ScrollController _slideUpPanelScrollController ) {
return Center(
    child: ConstrainedBox(
        constraints: const BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 600),
        child: ListView(
            controller: _slideUpPanelScrollController,
            physics: listViewScrollingOff
                ? const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()
                : const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            key: Key("scrollingPanelListView"),
            children: [
```

This is my onTap from my Drawer ListView item:

```
onTap: () {
  if(slidingPanelController.isPanelShown) {
  //slideUpPanelScrollController.jumpTo(0);
  slidingPanelController.close();
}
```

Love help!  Below is I think a minimum viable problem. I wrote it in Dartpad, but sharing from Dartpad is nontrivial, so I've copied and pasted it here. Dartpad doesn't support the plugin anyway so it's not like you could tweak it there.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:sliding_up_panel/sliding_up_panel.dart';

const Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  PanelController slidingPanelController = new PanelController();
  ScrollController slideUpPanelScrollController = new ScrollController();
  
  final String title = "sliding panel";
  
  String panelContent = "";
  String stupidText = "";
  String stupidText2 = ""
    
  int panelMinHeight = 0;
  int teaserPanelHeight = 77;
  
  bool listViewScrollingOff = false;
  
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    for(int i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
      stupidText += "More stupid text. ";
    }
    
     for(int i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
      stupidText2 += "More dumb, dumbest text. ";
    }
  }
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue,
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
              appBar: AppBar(title: Text(title)),
                drawer: Drawer(
  child: ListView(
    padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
    children: [
      const DrawerHeader(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.blue,
        ),
        child: Text('Drawer Header'),
      ),
      ListTile(
        title: const Text('Item 1'),
        onTap: () {
          if(slidingPanelController.isPanelShown) {
            print('attempting to scroll to top and close panel');
            //slideUpPanelScrollController.jumpTo(0);
            slidingPanelController.close();
          }
          Navigator.of(context).pop();
          setState() {
            panelContent = stupidText1;
            panelMinHeight = teaserPanelHeight;
          }
        },
      ),
      ListTile(
        title: const Text('Item 2'),
        onTap: () {
          if(slidingPanelController.isPanelShown) {
            //slideUpPanelScrollController.jumpTo(0);
            slidingPanelController.close();
          }
          Navigator.of(context).pop();
          setState() {
            panelContent = stupidText2;
            panelMinHeight = teaserPanelHeight;
          }
        }
      ),
    ],
  ),
),
        body: SlidingUpPanel(
        key: Key("slidingUpPanelKey"),
        borderRadius: 8,
        parallaxEnabled: false,
        controller: slidingPanelController,
        isDraggable: true,
        onPanelOpened: () async {
          setState(() {
            listViewScrollingOff = false;
            panelMinHeight = 0;
            animatedMarkerMap;
            //slideUpPanelScrollController.jumpTo(0);
          });
        },
        onPanelSlide: (value) {
          print("onPanelSlide: attempting to scroll panel");
        },
        onPanelClosed: () async {
          setState(() {
            //slideUpPanelScrollController.jumpTo(0);
            listViewScrollingOff = true;
          });
        },
        minHeight: panelMinHeight,
        maxHeight:
            MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - AppBar().preferredSize.height,
        // TODO BUG
        // SAM, IF I USE PANELBUILDER's ScrollController attached to the panel's ListView, then, when closing, the ListView will move to the top first, then the panel closes,
        // however ListView's controller is set to a globalController, this causes a bug when closing the panel, but means you can open/peek the panel from the App drawer,
        panelBuilder: (slideUpPanelScrollController) => _scrollingList(panelContent, slideUpPanelScrollController),
        
        body: Center(
          child: Text(
      'Hello, World!',
      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
    ),
        ),
          ),
      ),
    );
  }
  
    Widget _scrollingList(String panelContent, ScrollController _slideUpPanelScrollController ) {
    return Center(
        child: ConstrainedBox(
            constraints: const BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 600),
            child: ListView(
                controller: _slideUpPanelScrollController,
                physics: listViewScrollingOff
                    ? const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()
                    : const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                key: Key("scrollingPanelListView"),
                children: [Text(panelContent)])));
    }
}
```

OK, so the problem became that when I closed the sliding panel 'naturally', by scrolling back up the panel to it top then sliding the panel down, well both things happened at once.

I've found how to solve this, I need to set SlidingUpPanel's isDraggable property to false, till the user has scrolled to the top of the panel.

Like so...

```
      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
    
        slideUpPanelScrollController.addListener(() {
          if(slideUpPanelScrollController.offset == 0) {
            setState(() {
              isDraggableBool = true;
            });
          }
        });
}
```

The shortfall of this approach is the listener is running its test whenever the panel is Scrolled, could it jank the scroll? Is there a better/clearer/more performant way?

For completion I amended `setScrollBehaviour` to this:

```
      void setScrollBehavior(bool _canScroll, {resetPos = false}) {
    setState(() {
      canScroll = _canScroll;
      isDraggableBool = !_canScroll;
      if (resetPos) {
        slideUpPanelScrollController.jumpTo(0);
        isDraggableBool = true;
      }
    });
  }
```

So when the user can scroll they can't drag.
When the panel closes, `resetPos == true` therefore the panel scrolls to the top AND it can be dragged (slid) once more.

Comment: Listview might be the issue here. 
You could try to jump to the top before closing the panel instead of after.
You could also try to provide a key to your listview so it forces flutter to re-render.
Eventually, if it doesn't work wrap the body of the slide panel inside a signleChildScrollView and disable listview scrolling using physics.

It's a bit difficult to visualize a fix tho. If you can provide a link to dartpad (https://dartpad.dev) it would be much easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

==== UPDATE ====

you can clone panel builder scrolling behavior and use the controller freely elsewhere. that way, you don't have to worry much about listview scroll physic or panel states.

did some cleanup, added comments, and fixed the tap/scrolling issues.

The only drawback of this method is that the user has to scroll back to the top to close the panel (you can always wrap your body with a gesture and call resetPanel on tap if needed)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:sliding_up_panel/sliding_up_panel.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final PanelController panelController = PanelController();
  ScrollController? _scrollController;

  /// reset the content position of your listview
  void resetScrollBehavior() {
    // We make sure that our scroll exist and it is attached before reset
    if (_scrollController != null && _scrollController!.hasClients) {
      _scrollController!.jumpTo(0);
    }
  }

  /// close the panel and reset the scroll behavior
  void resetPanel() {
    // We make sure our panel is attached and open before executing
    if (panelController.isAttached && panelController.isPanelOpen) {
      panelController.close();
      // Remove this line if you wish to not reset the scrollExtent on panel reset.
      resetScrollBehavior();
    }
  }

  void onDrawerItemTap() {
    // Reset the panel and pop the screen
    resetPanel();
    Navigator.of(context).pop();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // we make sure to dispose our controller(s)
    _scrollController?.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      drawer: Drawer(
        child: ListView(
          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          children: [
            const DrawerHeader(
              child: Text('Drawer Header'),
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: const Text('Item 1'),
              onTap: () {
                onDrawerItemTap();
              },
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: const Text('Item 2'),
              onTap: () {
                onDrawerItemTap();
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      body: SlidingUpPanel(
        controller: panelController,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
        minHeight: 80,
        maxHeight:
            MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - AppBar().preferredSize.height,
        panelBuilder: (ScrollController sc) {
          // ! So we can use local scrollcontroller outside the panel builder
          _scrollController ??= sc;
          return ScrollingList(
            scrollController: _scrollController!,
          );
        },
        body: Center(
          child: Text(
            'Hello, World!',
            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ScrollingList extends StatefulWidget {
  const ScrollingList({
    Key? key,
    required this.scrollController,
  }) : super(key: key);
  final ScrollController scrollController;

  @override
  _ScrollingListState createState() => _ScrollingListState();
}

class _ScrollingListState extends State<ScrollingList> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: ConstrainedBox(
        constraints: const BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 600),
        child: ListView(
          controller: widget.scrollController,
          children: List.generate(200, (index) => Text('Text #$index')),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

=== OLD ===

Running some test, it seems that panelController.close();
also triggers onPanelClosed();
so you can take advantage of that to handle your scrolling behaviors.

The following sample demonstrates how you can reset your panel and/or listview by tapping on a drawer item.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:sliding_up_panel/sliding_up_panel.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  PanelController panelController = PanelController();
  ScrollController scrollController = ScrollController();

  bool canScroll = false;

  void onDrawerItemTap() {
    if (panelController.isAttached && panelController.isPanelOpen) {
      panelController.close();
    }
    Navigator.of(context).pop();
  }

  void setScrollBehavior(bool _canScroll, {resetPos = false}) {
    setState(() {
      canScroll = _canScroll;
      if (resetPos) {
        scrollController.jumpTo(0);
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      drawer: Drawer(
        child: ListView(
          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          children: [
            const DrawerHeader(
              child: Text('Drawer Header'),
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: const Text('Item 1'),
              onTap: () {
                onDrawerItemTap();
              },
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: const Text('Item 2'),
              onTap: () {
                onDrawerItemTap();
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      body: SlidingUpPanel(
        controller: panelController,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
        parallaxEnabled: false,
        isDraggable: true,
        onPanelOpened: () {
          setScrollBehavior(true);
        },
        onPanelSlide: (_) {
          // panel slide
        },
        onPanelClosed: () {
          setScrollBehavior(false, resetPos: true);
        },
        minHeight: 80,
        maxHeight:
            MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - AppBar().preferredSize.height,
        panelBuilder: (_) => ScrollingList(
          canScroll: canScroll,
          scrollController: scrollController,
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Text(
            'Hello, World!',
            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ScrollingList extends StatefulWidget {
  const ScrollingList({
    Key? key,
    this.canScroll = false,
    required this.scrollController,
  }) : super(key: key);
  final bool canScroll;
  final ScrollController scrollController;

  @override
  _ScrollingListState createState() => _ScrollingListState();
}

class _ScrollingListState extends State<ScrollingList> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: ConstrainedBox(
        constraints: const BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 600),
        child: ListView(
          controller: widget.scrollController,
          physics: !widget.canScroll
              ? const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()
              : const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          children: List.generate(200, (index) => Text('Text #$index')),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Phil, thanks for your thoughtful attention, I've reconfigured my code with the panel as a separate class as you suggest. However the effect is the same as my other cure.  What happens is the Scroll Position correctly returns to the top each time I select a new Drawer item BUT, when the Sliding panel is open and I scroll to the top it simultaneously starts closing the panel.  So you can't return to content you've sped past, because it is disappearing above the top of the closing panel. It's clearly a bug & poor UX.

Comment: There's an ``isDraggable`` boolean property on SlidingUpPanel, I think this needs to be false when folk are Scrolling the panel.  I'm not sure how to reach this from an external class.

Comment: OK I've solved the woozy Scroll up, sliding down issue with a listener on the ScollController.offset, as coded in my initState method above. I don't like how often this listener fires, so if you can conjure a more performant improvement I'll give you the bounty, for sheer effort Phil. Ultimately your refactor & its encouragement took me over the finish line, style is loved also.

Comment: Well, it has a small bug. If you open a panel, then try to immediately close it, the panel refuses to close, you need to scroll down, then back up THEN it'll allow you to close. Essentially until you scroll the ScollListener won't listen, therefore doesn't fire that ``scrollController.offset == 0`` as needed. I don't see a solution to this.

Comment: So to clarify you want to scroll to the top when a drawer item is pressed but not when a user closes the panel naturally?

Regarding offset and listeners, I wouldn't recommend that method first because a listener is really expensive and second because offset can have negative values which is the case here that why you have that issue now.

Comment: turns out the scroll controller that is required for the listview is the one the panelBuilder provides. Otherwise it gets terribly messy. However I found an alternative. I'll update my post with a proper example. @Sam

Comment: Cheers Phil! This is the line which helped so so SOO much ``_scrollController ??= sc;`` I never thought of assigning the ScrollController there, it's brilliant, and I hadn't seen that format before, it makes sense, given only 1 ScrollController is generated that you need only assign once, which is the case if it is ``null``. Happy days. I had to retain the ``physics: widget.canScrollList
                    ? const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics() : const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),``
To ensure the list didn't scroll before the panel was completely opened. Huzzah! All bugs solved.

Answer (score 0):

[ListView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView-class.html) might be the issue here. You could try to jump to the top before closing the panel instead of after. You could also try to provide a key to your ListView so it forces flutter to re-render. Eventually, if it doesn't work wrap the body of the slide panel inside a [SingleChildScrollview](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SingleChildScrollView-class.html) and disable ListView scrolling using physics. It's a bit difficult to visualize a fix though. If you can provide a link to [DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/) it would be much easier.

Comment: I've put a minimum example at the bottom. I tried exporting from Dartpad but it was non-trivial, at least from Dartpad's Flutter view it does not offer an automatic way to upload to GitHub, which is where their docs suggests saving stuff to share.